# Order by related field that relates to another field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

**Scenario**: Custom datatable with products, columns being different fields with ability to sort by those fields' values

**Desired results**: Upon sorting a specific field, results are sorted by the field's values

**Prisma model**:

```
model Field {
  id            String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String     <-- Sortable key
  productFields ProductField[]
}

model ProductField {
  id        String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  fieldId   String  @db.ObjectId
  field     Field   @relation(fields: [fieldId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String  @db.ObjectId
  value     String      <-- Sort target
}

model Product {
  id            String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name          String
  productFields ProductField[]
  
}
```

I expect the syntax to be something like this:

```
await prisma.product.findMany({
    ...,
    orderBy: {
             productFields: {
                some: {
                   field: {
                      name: fieldName,
                   },
                   value: 'asc',
                 },
              },
          };
})
```

However, I get this error:

```
Unknown arg `some` in orderBy.productFields.some for type ProductFieldOrderByRelationAggregateInput. Did you mean `select`? Available args:
type ProductFieldOrderByRelationAggregateInput {
      _count?: SortOrder
}
```

Is there a proper way to  perform this complex sorting query or it Prisma isn't able to do this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this sort even in Raw SQL, because one Product can have multiple ProductFields related to it. But you can do the inverse, getting the ProductFields in Order and relationing with Products.

```
await prisma.productfield.findMany({
...,
orderBy: {
         yourFieldName: "asc"
      },
select: {
   product: true
    }
})
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way to do it. Its a shame that it creates a lot of if statements when sort is expected to be by field or by product name, but it is how it is